# Heroku - FATAL: password authentication failed for user <>

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, heroku, spring-boot

First of all, I created PostgreSQL DB in Heroku. I **manually** created my DB/schema/tables through pgAdmin remote access. I know I succeeded since it updated my row limit.

Now, I am deploying a Spring Boot application.
No DB props/credentials are found in my `application.properties` file since I am supposed to do this in Heroku **Config Vars**. For example, my DB username is **janxgspmlpjgbn**

Project builds successfully, however, in the logs I see that it has this exception.

```
2016-09-28 16:12:31.184 [ERROR] org.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog.log:181 - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
2016-09-28T16:12:31.185772+00:00 app[web.1]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "u24453"
```

### Question

Why does it fail for the user **u24453** (by the way this user changes every time I redeploy) when in my Config Var, I typed the user **janxgspmlpjgbn**?

### Edit

Here's how my **Config Vars** look right now:
[image]

Comment: You mentioned that you "typed" your config var. Are you not using the `DATABASE_URL` Heroku provides for you?

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if it's using the DATABASE_URL or the SPRING_DATASOURCE_ variables that I "typed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`u24453` is probably the OS user name (the one Heroku creates for your app as it runs on Ubuntu Linux).

I believe the Postgres Driver will use the OS username as your DB username by default (if a username is not provided). Thus, I suspect the DB username is not getting into the configuration properly.

In your `application.yml` you should have this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
    username: ${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
    password: ${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

For more info see [Connecting to Relational Databases on Heroku with Java](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java)

Comment: It probably is since I checked the login-roles for the database and DB usernames don't look like that.

I see! I believe I am missing this one. I thought it automatically maps based on what I setup in the Config Vars. I'll try this right now.

Comment: Perfect! It's now working! Thanks a lot! (Closing ticket in Heroku)